# Why redux store only get value of last dispatch Action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to make multi dispatch action in the action phase of redux:

Here is my code:

```
export const get_data_time_slot_week = (params) => {
return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: common.CALL_API_REQUEST,
    });
    const res = await callAPI.post(TIME_SLOT_WEEK + GET, {
        params: { ...params },
    });

    if (res.status === 200 && res.data.code >= 0) {

//Here, I get new state of Selector timeSlotWeek
        dispatch({
            type: timeSlotWeek.GET_DATA_TIME_SLOT_WEEK_SUCCESS,
            payload: {
                data: [...res.data.data],
                dataPage: { ...res.data.dataPage },
                errCode: res.data.code,
            },
        });

//And here, I lost state of a Selector timeSlotWeek add get new state of Selector common
        dispatch({
            type: common.GET_FEEDBACK,
            payload: {
                msg: "__msg_can_not_to_server",
            },
        });
    }
};
```

};

Why did it happen? And how can i keep the state of timeSlotWeek with same flow in my code ?

This is my result when i check by Redux tool

```
GET_DATA_TIME_SLOT_WEEK_SUCCESS     =>    data: { 0: {...}, 1{...} }
GET_FEEDBACK                        =>    data: {}
                                          msg: "new msg"
```

This is my store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

This is my {combineReducers}

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import feedback from "./feedback.reducer";
import loadingReducer from "./loading.reducer";
import timeSlotWeek from "./timeSlotWeek.reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    dataTimeSlotWeek: timeSlotWeek,
    loading: loadingReducer,
    feedback: feedback,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Thanks for your help

UPDATE: Problem solve:
Because in my reducer of timeSlotWeek.reducer I have a default case, and when I dispatch another action, this case will run and make the state of timeSlotWeek become initState.

```
import { common, timeSlotWeek } from "../actions/constants";
const initState = {
    data: [],
};

    export default (state = initState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case timeSlotWeek.GET_DATA_TIME_SLOT_WEEK_SUCCESS:
                state = {
                    // Pass payload to this
                };
                break;
            default:
                state = { ...initState };
        }
        return state;
    };
```

I fix it by this way:

```
import { common, timeSlotWeek } from "../actions/constants";

const initState = {
    data: [],
};

export default (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case timeSlotWeek.GET_DATA_TIME_SLOT_WEEK_SUCCESS:
            state = {
                // Pass payload to this
            };
            break;
        **case common.CALL_API_FINISH:
            state = state;
            break;
        case common.GET_FEEDBACK:
            state = state;
            break;**
        default:
            state = { ...initState };
    }
    return state;
};
```

Have any way better than my way ? Thank for cmt

Comment: What does "lost state of a Selector timeSlotWeek add get new state of Selector common" even mean? Issue seems to be in your reducers, can you add those to your question?

Comment: when i dispatch timeSlotWeek.GET_DATA_TIME_SLOT_WEEK_SUCCESS, 
Selector.timeSlotWeek  have some value,  and when type: common.GET_FEEDBACK
 run, Selector.timeSlotWeek  become to initState

Comment: What is `Selector.timeSlotWeek`? I see no such thing in your question/code snippets. What do you mean "when I dispatch /`timeSlotWeek.GET_DATA_TIME_SLOT_WEEK_SUCCESS`/`. Are you manually dispatching actions via the redux-dev-tool? Are you also sending `payload` values? What becomes "initState" and what is "initState"? Please try to share all relevant code. I still think we need to see what your reducers are doing with these actions.

Comment: Thank you give me a way to fix. U can see my Update in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default reducer case should always return the current state object. I can't think of a single counter-example otherwise (*though I have seen some tutorials throw an error here you generally don't want to do that as it adds unnecessary error handling and complicates everything*).

You need only define cases for actions your state slice reducer needs to handle, otherwise the let the default case handle it by simply returning the current state.

```
const initState = {
  data: [],
};

export default (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case timeSlotWeek.GET_DATA_TIME_SLOT_WEEK_SUCCESS:
      return {
        // Pass payload to this
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

If you need to reset *some* state then use another action and case for this, i.e.:

```
case 'resetTimeSlotWeek':
  return initState;
```

Comment: Agreed!  Resetting to the initial state on default is crazy.